# Is this a bug in DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(string searchPattern)?

Tags: c#, .net

When calling [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(".")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3e2f6e5.aspx) on an instance of a DirectoryInfo class which points to a valid folder (excluding drive roots), the result is a DirectoryInfo array whose first (and only) element points to a invalid directory named the same as itself, below itself.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp");
    DirectoryInfo[] dis = di.GetDirectories(".");
    Console.WriteLine(dis[0].FullName);
}
```

Prints out a non-existent directory:

```
c:\temp\temp
```

I understand that in Windows, a "." refers to the current directory.  That might be acceptable to me if the method returned "c:\temp", but returning a fake subdirectory with the same name seems like absolutely the wrong behavior.

**I should be able to assert that any DirectoryInfo object returned from this function actually exists....  right?!**

I decompiled the class using .NET Reflector, but it leads to this method

```
internal static string[] InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(string path, string userPathOriginal, string searchPattern, bool includeFiles, bool includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)"
```

Which is a BEAST and I don't feel like walking through the logic in my head.  It's clearly a bug IMHO.

FYI - a "*" works as expected, before someone asks.

Comment: Interesting that the help mentions .. but not .

Comment: You have a good point.  However, isn't this one of those things thats "always been this way" and everyone always filters out the . and .. directory listings?

Comment: @ScottCher in DOS if I do "dir ." in a directory, I don't get any non-existent results. I just get "." and ".." (both of which exist)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm what you say, and can't see any rational explanation for it, so I'm voting **BUG**.

I think so as well, I [submitted it](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=378565) to Microsoft