# Directory.GetFiles searchPattern inconsistent with documentation

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen this question: [Is this a bug in DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(string searchPattern)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250834/is-this-a-bug-in-directoryinfo-getdirectoriesstring-searchpattern)

It is not entirely consistent with my problem, so I'll ask anyway.

My code is:

```
var pattern = @"file.*";
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(".", pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

In my current directory I have `file` and `file.txt`. As (un)expected, both files are found.

Is it a bug or is it documented **somewhere**? I've found this issue on Mono and wanted to file a bug there, but I've checked on VS2012 first and it seems to occur as well...

Of course I know how to filter the result, but it... angers me anyway, so I'd like to know the sources.

Comment: [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documents some quirks for the search pattern (under its "Notes"), which were implemented to retroactively support the 8.3 filename convention. I assume the behaviour you're observing is another consequence of this.

Comment: And that's exactly what I would like to have documented...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how Windows (and DOS) interpret wildcards. Unlike UNIX, Windows at one time actually distinguished, internally, between the "name" portion of a filename and the "extension" portion (this is where the notorious "8.3" limit comes from). It doesn't really make this internal distinction anymore, but the legacy of this lives on in Windows.

So Windows/DOS search patterns search for two components, the name, and the extension. The pattern `file.*` matches any file named `file` with an extension of `*` (i.e., any extension at all). Both `file` and `file.txt` meet this criteria.

I would tend to agree that this doesn't make a lot of sense, but that's how it is.

Comment: Is that behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy There's probably more authoritative info out there, but [I did find this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) that talks about it, at the bottom of the article.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy not explicitly, but this is documentation for the GetFiles-Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx If you also take into account that `.` is no wildcard in the (Win-)Dos-World but a seperator it makes perfect sense

Comment: I think it's documented indirectly since [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions that it searches both the long file name format and [**8.3 filenames**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). There is specified that "files with no extension, the `"."`, if present, has no significance".

Comment: Well, thank you for your input. I wonder how is it done on Mono, since it works the same way on Linux - must be a lot of code to emulate this behaviour. Anyway, while I understand legacy reasons, I think this is plainly stupid. How hard would it be to allow both options? Well...

Comment: In the early versions of Microsoft DOS the "." was not actually stored on the disk, it was only implied. Eight bytes were allocated for the name and three bytes for the "extension" -- whether they were needed or not. This leads to the "." having no significance if "present" -- it's not really *ever* present in the name as stored on disk.